# Kendo Grid Pop Up edit not firing Controller method on save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a kendo grid with enabled pop Up editing. It doesnt fire the controller method on update. Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Trabaho.Model.Models.ProfileApplicationSubset>()
.Name("Assessment")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Position).Width(200).Groupable(true);
        columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.MiddleName).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.LastName).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DesiredSalary).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Email).Width(150).Groupable(true);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Mobile).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Region).Width(300);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Province).Width(300);
        //columns.Bound(c => c.Region).Width(150);
        //columns.Bound(c => c.Province).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.City).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Barangay).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Gender).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Recruiter).Width(150).Groupable(true);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(160);
    })
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
.Navigatable()
.Pageable(page => page
        .ButtonCount(5)
        .PageSizes(new[] { 50, 100, 500,1000 })
        .Refresh(true))
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Filterable()

.Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
.Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
.ColumnMenu()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(500)
    .Read(read => read.Action("_GetForAssessment", "DashBoard"))
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => { model.Id(p=>p.ApplicationId); model.Field(p => p.ApplicationId); })
    .Update(update => update.Action("_Assessment", "DashBoard"))
    .Update(read => read.Type(HttpVerbs.Post))



)
)

<script type="text/javascript">
 function error_handler(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Errors:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function () {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

And in the controller method i have these actions to update and read

```
        public ActionResult _GetForAssessment([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var user = GetLinkedProfile(true);
        var jsons = _applicationService.GetApplicantsForAssesments("Metro Manila").ToList();
        return Json(jsons.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult _Assessment([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ProfileApplicationSubset model)
    {
        if (model == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
            return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        var jobApp = _applicationService.Find(model.ApplicationId);
        jobApp.EmploymentStatus = model.ApplicationStatus;
        jobApp.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;
        _applicationService.Update(jobApp);
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

the Controller name is DashBoard, The console window shows no Error but the breakpoint in the the update method is not hit..
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my configuration??

Comment: Did you change the value of any field in popup form when updating your model? Kendo grid does not fire update action until you change something in your popup form.

Comment: Yes I update the field of the date but still the same

Comment: Try to replace this

.Update(update => update.Action("_Assessment", "DashBoard"))
.Update(read => read.Type(HttpVerbs.Post))

with this

.Update(update => update.Action("_Assessment", "DashBoard").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))

Answer (score -1):

```
use this one 
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Trabaho.Model.Models.ProfileApplicationSubset>()
.Name("Assessment")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Position).Width(200).Groupable(true);
        columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.MiddleName).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.LastName).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DesiredSalary).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Email).Width(150).Groupable(true);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Mobile).Width(150).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Region).Width(300);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Province).Width(300);
        //columns.Bound(c => c.Region).Width(150);
        //columns.Bound(c => c.Province).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.City).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Barangay).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Gender).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Recruiter).Width(150).Groupable(true);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(160);
    })
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
.Navigatable()
.Pageable(page => page
        .ButtonCount(5)
        .PageSizes(new[] { 50, 100, 500,1000 })
        .Refresh(true))
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Filterable()

.Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
.Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
.ColumnMenu()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(500)
    .Read(read => read.Action("_GetForAssessment", "DashBoard"))
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => { model.Id(p=>p.ApplicationId); model.Field(p => p.ApplicationId); })
  .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateLockinProductContents", "PackageContent"))
)
)




[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult UpdateLockinProductContents([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<ModalName> model)
        {}
```

Comment: no explanation of what you did to fix it? so here i am, found this via google - and i need to do a file compare just to try and understand you answer..